# How to extract text from components in Angular 6 for translation (ngx-translate)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to find a way to fetch all text strings in my Angular 6 projects files (ts and styles and html files) so that the nested JSON Objects are automagically generated using the files path. E.g. in component html file:

app/shared/forms/categories/categories.component.html:

```html
<a id="input-categories">This string</a>
<a class="btn accept">This button</a>
```

after extraction, in en.json:

```js
{
  "shared": {
    "forms": {
      "categories":{
         "a-input-categories": "This string",
         "a-btn-accept": "This button"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've had a look at [ngx-translate-extract](https://github.com/biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract), but it will only extract already translatable `{{ name.space.here | translate }}` pipes etc.

If this is impossible, is there a way to "mark" each string using some default marker such as `trans` in this fashion:

```html
<a id="input-categories" trans>This string</a>
<a class="btn accept" trans>This button</a>
```

My problem is that the front end dev has hardcoded everything, and now we are looking at a 4 digit number of strings that is required to be pulled out of the markup and code for translation.

Comment: Have you tried the [i18n guilde in angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#mark-text-with-the-i18n-attribute)? The `ng xi18n` tool [can extract from your app](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#create-a-translation-source-file-with-ng-xi18n) all text, and put it in a translation friendly XLIFF file. You can then convert that file to JSON if you wish.

Comment: Some of the text is already converted to `{{ some.thing | translate }}` and moved to the corresponding files in assets/i18n. I was hoping for some quick and dirty, which can translate the hard coded string to `{{ some.thing | translate }}` while it collects the content and adds it to the lang.json file

Answer (score 2):

you can ngx-translate-extractor

https://github.com/biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract

```
ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output ./src/assets/i18n/template.json
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [text2locale](https://github.com/juliandavidmr/text2locale).

```sh
npm install -g github:juliandavidmr/text2locale
```

Extract and generate JSON files:

```sh
text2locale input "./example/src" -o "./example/locale/" -l en -t es,de,zh
```

Comment: Thanks, This is working fine @anlijudavid. Can we change the text to the json key in the angular component.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that might help you is:

```
<(.+)( .*)?>(.*[a-zA-Z]+.*)<\/\1>
```

Write give the following regex to a Replace tool in a text editor, it will catch all tags with text inside them.

Then replace the first tag's contents, with (for VS Code)

```
<$1 i18n $2>$3</$1>
```

or maybe for other editors:

```
<\1 i18n \2>\3<\/\1>
```

This will convert every `<tag attribute="value" etc>stuff</tag>` to `<tag i18n attribute="value" etc>stuff</tag>`.

Then you can use `ng xi18n` to automatically extract all text for translation to XLIFF.

This assumes that your html templates are formatted like:

```
<tag>
   <subtag> text </subtag>
</tag>
```

Which means only one tag with text per line (`<tag><subtag>` in the same line might create an issue), and  that text is in the same line as its enclosing tags.

Comment: kudos for the effort!, But what you propose is way to dangerous to perform on a entire code base. Especially when you are using regex with HTML, there are way to many edge cases.

Comment: Yes I thought so. Still if you do it manually, it may speed up your process. There is no other way that I know of, unfortunately, for a parser to recognize text that needs to be translated inside HTML.